# Make Checkbox's text a clickable link in Android Studio(KOTLIN) which opens up a certain website?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was making this app which contains a 1000s of links in a scrollview linear layout and the text in the checkbox looks like this ---> Link 1
Now I want it to open a particular link when it is clicked and the checkbox gets a tick mark right after 15 seconds. How can I do it in kotlin?

This is my main activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {

    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<MainActivity> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): MainActivity {
            return MainActivity(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MainActivity?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68sp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/untitled_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallet_icon_final" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="49dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/rupee_icon"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Link"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your text spannable string.

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with a url span");
string.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.developer.android.com"), 12, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

yourCheckbox.setText(string);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan